# Get submitted date data from db?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, date

Struggling to get correct submitted data date from mysql db! It display wrong date!

Like **Date added: October 2020**, but instead it show yesterday date.

*query function*

```
{
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM filmdb ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Tallinn");
        $film_added = $fetch['film_added'];
        $date = strtotime($film_added);
        $filmpostdate = date("F j, Y",$date);
    }
}
```

*displaying*

```
 <li><span><strong>Date added:</strong></span>'.$filmpostdate.'</li>
```

SQL table
[image: SQL table]

Added requested information included **film_added** column
[image: requested information]

Comment: Well look at your logic.  Your variable `$filmpostdate` is being replaced for each iteration of the `while` loop.  So obviously when you display it, it will only contain the date of the latest record.

Comment: So this is correct? `{
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM filmdb");
 while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
 {
     date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Tallinn");
     $film_added = $fetch['film_added'];
        $date = strtotime($film_added);
        $film_added = date("F j, Y",$date);
 }
} `

Comment: So what do you mean by "wrong date"???  What date do you want to display???

Comment: Date when i submitted

Answer (score 0):

with your SQL being

```
SELECT * FROM filmdb ORDER BY id DESC
```

and then going through a loop, setting the variable and then displaying it (as your code shows) you will only get the LAST piece of data from the table.

Show your data that is in the table (all of it - with a picture or type it) and we can help you better.

Also, you don't have any way to select the 'October' entry - your sql is only 'By id'.

You need some other way to select (dozens of ways are possible so it is hard to give you an answer yet without more idea of how you have your data entered (again, a list or picture of all data will help us answer).

To get the 'October' entry, you might change your sql to something more specific (like a specific id you looked up before, etc.....)

Give us the full columns of the table as well as lines of entered data (you can block out any 'personal' stuff - we don't care about the entries, just need more info to help out!)

EDIT:  All your data dates are exactly the same (which sounds like it is an issue with the entry portion of your program.....)

The datetime in MySQL table is related to the server time (as you have tried to set in your code), though also related to the ENTERED time.  So, if you entered the time as GMT, then when you try to display it with 'Europe/Tallinn', it may change again.....

Timezone stuff gets confusing - my recommendation is to always work with GMT until you show it to the user.

You can research on working with timezone - I will address your direct question (it seems like you need a lot of instruction and I'll help as I can, though you may need to ask other questions....)

You asked why your request shows yesterday's date.  It is because of something in the timezone and stored date.

To get the date to show 'October', remove the line

```
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Tallinn");
```

The date should show what you want.

Now, you may want to get the date that is being entered (again, this is a setting of your input program and the server) - set the 'e' on the date format.

```
    $filmpostdate = date("F j, Y e",$date);
```

From there you should see the info that is in the database.

Now, you want to see the date RELATIVE TO YOUR TIMEZONE (what your question is in the original post....)  Try this....

```
 $filmpostdate = date("F j, Y",strtotime($date . " Europe/Tallinn);
```

It may still not be what you want, but with all this you should be able to now understand better about timezones and have some ways to troubleshoot things.

If you need more help, you may need a different post.  I trust this answers your original question as well as gives additional help for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not chosen the default data type of column film_added to current timestamp. If yes, then go ahead and change the data type of column film_added to current timestamp.